# Control ASdisplayNode height is consistent with cell height

Tags: asyncdisplaykit

How do you make the control ASdisplayNode highly consistent with the cell?

```
-  (ASLayoutSpec *)layoutSpecThatFits:(ASSizeRange)constrainedSize{
NSMutableArray *rightArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:_titleNode, _descNode,nil];
[rightArray addObjectsFromArray:_replayNodes];
ASStackLayoutSpec *verStackLayout = [ASStackLayoutSpec stackLayoutSpecWithDirection:ASStackLayoutDirectionVertical spacing:8 justifyContent:ASStackLayoutJustifyContentStart alignItems:ASStackLayoutAlignItemsStart children:rightArray];
verStackLayout.style.flexGrow = YES;
verStackLayout.style.flexShrink  = YES;
self.dateNode.style.preferredSize =  CGSizeMake(130 ,50);//How high is the height of cell?
self.dateNode.style.flexShrink = YES;
 ASStackLayoutSpec *horStackLayout = [ASStackLayoutSpec stackLayoutSpecWithDirection:ASStackLayoutDirectionHorizontal spacing:10 justifyContent:ASStackLayoutJustifyContentStart alignItems:ASStackLayoutAlignItemsStart children:@[self.dateNode,verStackLayout]];
horStackLayout.style.flexShrink = YES;
return horStackLayout;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Ecu.png)

Comment: look on this example: https://github.com/TextureGroup/Texture/tree/master/examples/VerticalWithinHorizontalScrolling

Comment: Thank you, but it's not my problem. My line varies with the height of the ASTableNode-cell. It's not a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and tell what you got?

```
-  (ASLayoutSpec *)layoutSpecThatFits:(ASSizeRange)constrainedSize{
NSMutableArray *rightArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:_titleNode, _descNode,nil];
[rightArray addObjectsFromArray:_replayNodes];
ASStackLayoutSpec *verStackLayout = [ASStackLayoutSpec stackLayoutSpecWithDirection:ASStackLayoutDirectionVertical spacing:8 justifyContent:ASStackLayoutJustifyContentStart alignItems:ASStackLayoutAlignItemsStretch children:rightArray];
verStackLayout.style.flexGrow = YES;
verStackLayout.style.flexShrink  = YES;
self.dateNode.style.flexShrink = YES;
ASStackLayoutSpec *horStackLayout = [ASStackLayoutSpec stackLayoutSpecWithDirection:ASStackLayoutDirectionHorizontal spacing:10 justifyContent:ASStackLayoutJustifyContentStart alignItems:ASStackLayoutAlignItemsStretch children:@[self.dateNode,verStackLayout]];
horStackLayout.style.flexShrink = YES;
horStackLayout.style.flexGrow = YES;
horStackLayout.style.alignSelf = ASStackLayoutAlignItemsStretch;
return horStackLayout;
}
```

Comment: self.dateNode  is not preferredSize. It cannot be displayed .

Comment: Cannot calculate size of node: constrainedSize is infinite and node does not override -calculateSizeThatFits: or specify a preferredSize. Try setting style.preferredSize. Node: <<ASDisplayNode: 0x7fd9f270a280> alpha:1.00 isLayerBacked:1 frame:{{0, 0}, {0, 0}} (null)>

Comment: @freda can u share simple example, i'll try do ur task.